# Enabling the live broadcastings via API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to use Youtube API for working with streaming video. By default, the streaming video is always disabled in account, but it can be turned on via the interface.
But when using the Service Account, it is unclear how to do it, because there is no access to the interface.

Please advise, how can I enable working with streaming video for Service Account?

Comment: I think this question might be better off at http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: OK: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76240/enabling-the-live-broadcastings-via-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the YouTube API with service accounts -- it just isn't available.

For the live streaming API, then, your users would have to turn it on in their own accounts, and then authorize to your app via oAuth2 to grant your app ability to control streams.